# Select Table Dialog Box

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-word, mailmerge

I am using an Access database to query line items for a project, send it out to an Excel spreadsheet in the Job folder on the server, copy a master word document to the folder, execute a mail-merge with the Excel spreadsheet as the data source. Then save the merged document to the job folder. It worked fabulously on all of the users machines, with no errors. The user only needs to be looking at the correct record on the form, and click a button. Everything happened in the background. Until a couple of weeks ago, when my development machine crashed and I needed a replacement. Since I started on the new machine, the VBA code hangs on my code wrdDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource (oFile). It took days to figure out that I had to go to the task manager, select Word, then double click on the Select Table option and it would bring the Select Table dialog (from Word) to the foreground. I could click through that and then the code runs fine.  Unfortunately, I can't find a way to eliminate this step, and I have users who aren't going to be advanced enough to perform the steps. If I copy my development front-end to a user machine, apparently this "feature" of pausing this process gets dragged with it.

There's a little green leaf next to the Select Table task that pops-up this message: ""This UWP process is suspended to improve system performance". Is there a way to eliminate this suspension or to go around it? I have been trying in VBA for 2 days to get past this problem.

Here's my code:

```
oFile = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(qry, dbOpenSnapshot)("FilePath") &    "\sheet1$.xls"

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "qryCOPILineItems",    acFormatXLS, oFile, False
 
Set wrdApp =CreateObject("Word.Application")
 
Set wrdDoc =wrdApp.Documents.Open(destFile, False, False, False, , , , , ,wdFormLetters, , True)
 
wrdDoc.MailMerge.OpenDataSource (oFile)
```

---this is where it hangs up and I have to use the Task Manager to force it to run

```
wrdDoc.MailMerge.Destination = wdSendToNewDocument 
   
wrdDoc.MailMerge.Execute (True)

wrdApp.Visible = True  
  
wrdApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 destFile2 

wrdApp.Documents.Open destFile2
```

I've tried setting alerts to none in VBA, tried to get a handle on the Window, I've tried all sorts of options to eliminate this "pause" but I'm currently at my wits end. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need:

```
wrdApp.DisplayAlerts = False
```

to eliminate the SQL prompmt - which also causes Word to open the document as an ordinary, non-mailmerge, document. So then you will also need to encode the data connection, etc. For example:

```
Dim StrMMSrc As String
StrMMSrc = ThisWorkbook.FullName
With wrdDoc
  With .MailMerge
    .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
    .OpenDataSource Name:=StrMMSrc, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
      LinkToSource:=False, Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;" & _
      "Data Source=StrMMSrc;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";", _
      SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet1$`"
    End With
  Next
End With
```

Before doing that, you can check all the required parameters in your existing mailmerge main document using code like:

```
Sub Test()
With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
  If .MainDocumentType <> wdNotAMergeDocument Then
    MsgBox "Mail Merge Data Source Name:" & vbCr & .DataSource.Name
    MsgBox "Mail Merge Connect String:" & vbCr & .DataSource.ConnectString
    MsgBox "Mail Merge Query String:" & vbCr & .DataSource.QueryString
  Else
    MsgBox "Not A Merge Document"
  End If
End With
End Sub
```

See also the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** page at https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html
and especially the *Run a Mailmerge from Excel, Sending the Output to Individual Files* topic there.